# Chrome 42 console cannot copy object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I am trying to inspect an javascript Object from a jQuery Event. When I right click the object and `Set as Global Variable`, a new object `temp1` is created.

Then I tried to do command: `copy(temp1)`

The following results appears:

> DOMException: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('radio') does not support selection.

I am using Chrome 42

Comment: For reference, here's [the API docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#copyobject).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this bug. Can you provide an example where you're seeing this behavior?